# Creating a sign up and log in page using Java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to create two page which is sign up and log in page using Java. What I'm trying to create is just a console, thus no GUI is required. Now, I'm creating a sign up page which you can be either a student or a tutor, using array to store user input and when user log in, it will check for the user input in sign up page.

Information required (get user input) for sign up: email, password, username, contact, credentials

Currently, I'm stuck at the array part inside the switch statement, i'm not quite sure how to implement arrays / arraylist inside switch. Here's what i got:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class assgn {

        public static void  main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<userType> users = new ArrayList<userType>(); // store and hold user input temporary
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // to obtain input from user

            String email, password, username, subject, credentials;
            int contact;

            System.out.println("========== SIGN UP PAGE ==========");
            System.out.println("Pick your choice:  ");
            System.out.println("1) Student" + "\n" + "2) Tutor");
            int choice = input.nextInt();

            switch(choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("========== Student Account ==========");
                    //arrays goes here
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("========== Tutor Account ==========");
                    //arrays goes here
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Please pick your account type");
            }
        }

    }
```

and below is the class file:

```
public class userType {
    private String email, password, username, subject, credentials;
    private int contact;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void newEmail (String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void newPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void newUsername (String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getSubject (){
        return subject;
    }

    public void newSubject (String subject){
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    public void newCredentials(){
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public int getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void newContact (int contact){
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public userType(String email, String password, String username, String subject, String credentials){
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public userType(int contact){
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance cheers

Comment: what is your actual question? it would also do good to follow naming conventions, it will make your code easier to read/understand for others

Comment: If you want to add a user to the ArrayList you can firstly create the `userType` object in your switch branch by getting the user to enter their details, then add this object to the array list using `add` method

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names always start with uppercase. It is also very common in the Java world that mutator methods (your `newSubject`, `newUsername` etc. methods) start with the word "set" (i.e. `setSubject`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use what you've already made to add them to the `users` ArrayList.

```
switch (choice) {
case 1:
    System.out.println("========== Student Account ==========");
    users.add(new userType(email, password, username, subject, credentials));
    break;

case 2:
    System.out.println("========== Tutor Account ==========");
    users.add(new userType(email, password, username, subject, credentials));
    break;

default:
    System.out.println("Please pick your account type");
}
```

You'd still need to get the user to fill in their `email`, `password`, `username`, `subject` and `credentials` ofcourse. Besides that I would add something to the constructor of `userType` so you can identify if the user is a tutor or student.

And I'd change the classname `userType` to `UserType`, which is a java naming convention.

Comment: i agree with @Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code.

```
        ArrayList<userType> student = new ArrayList<userType>(); // store and hold user(student) input temporary
        ArrayList<userType> tutor = new ArrayList<userType>(); // store and hold user(tutor) input temporary

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("========== Student Account ==========");

            System.out.print("email : "); // input userType information (email, password ...)
            email = input.next();
            System.out.print("password : ");
            password = input.next();
            System.out.print("username : ");
            username = input.next();
            System.out.print("subject : ");
            subject = input.next();
            System.out.print("credentials : ");
            credentials = input.next();

            student.add(new userType(email, password, username, subject, credentials));
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("========== Tutor Account ==========");

            System.out.print("email : "); // input userType information (email, password ...)
            email = input.next();
            System.out.print("password : ");
            password = input.next();
            System.out.print("username : ");
            username = input.next();
            System.out.print("subject : ");
            subject = input.next();
            System.out.print("credentials : ");
            credentials = input.next();

            tutor.add(new userType(email, password, username, subject, credentials));
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Please pick your account type");
        }
```

The user can input his or her own information. And you can identify whether the user is a tutor or a student.